# Difference between two delete queries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to delete some data from a table variable using a SELECT query.  The following code works perfectly:

```
DECLARE @sgID int
SET @sgID = 1234

DELETE FROM
    @tbl_users 
WHERE
    (userID NOT IN (
            SELECT
                userID 
            FROM
                [SGTable] 
            WHERE
                (sgID = @sgID)
            ))
```

I'm trying to speed up this query, and read that the following approach may be better.  However, when I use the following code - ALL records are deleted from the table variable.

```
DELETE
    tmp 
FROM 
    @tbl_Users tmp INNER JOIN
    [SGTable] sgu ON sgu.userID = tmp.userID 
WHERE
    (sgu.sgID <> @sgID)
```

I (obviously incorrectly) assumed that these two queries did the same thing (delete all userIDs in the table variable where the userID is not found in the sub-query).  Can anyone please offer some advice on making the second query work, as it is obviously easier to read and maintain?

Comment: Can't you replace `DELETE` with `SELECT *` and see the result set?

Comment: Yes and the select shows all the userIDs that should be deleted from the table variable.  I don't get why the delete statement therefore removes all the other rows as well... :-\

Comment: Figured it out, it was because a userID can be associated with more than one sgID.  Stupid stupid me.  Thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that a userID can be associated with more than one sgID in SGTable?

If so, then you're deleting users in your sgID (@sgID) because they are also associated with another sgID.

You might prefer:

```
DELETE tmp 
FROM @tbl_Users tmp 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [SGTable] sgu ON sgu.userID = tmp.userID AND sgu.sgID = @sgID
WHERE sgu.sgID IS NULL
```

Comment: I cannot believe how stupid I am.  Yes you are completely correct.  The reason for the question though was to find a faster way to search the table variable.  According to Gail at SQL in the Wild, LEFT OUTER JOIN is slower than IN because of extra filtering required.  I guess I might have to stick to my original plan using IN...

Comment: I think Gail is right (I've found the NOT IN to be faster as well). I was just offering an alternative if you thought the simpler maintenance was more important than the performance difference (might be, depending on table sizes).  And, it's not stupid to not notice something like this.  It's much easier to find issues in somebody else's query. :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about a `delete where exists`?

```
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM ....)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that where clause be "=" rather than "<>" ?  You want to delete the record that matches, not the ones that don't (which might be all of them), right?